# Custom ListView from Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to populate a list view from an `ArrayList` but for some reason it only grabs the last record. The array holds the data correctly and if I change the I to a number it will print the selected value.

My code is below any help would be appreciated.

```
  ArrayList<String> tests = new ArrayList();
    for(HashMap<String, String> test : outageData){
        String outagenumber = test.get("outagenum");
        Log.v("Outage",outagenumber);

     tests.add(outagenumber);
    }
    SectionListItem[] exampleArray = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++) {
        exampleArray = new SectionListItem[]{

                new SectionListItem("test", tests.get(i)),


        };
    }

    CustomOutageDetailListAdapter adapter = new CustomOutageDetailListAdapter(this, exampleArray);
    sectionAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(),
                adapter);
```

This is the adapter for fill List.

```
public class SectionOutageListItem {
public Object item;
public String section;

    public SectionOutageListItem(final Object item, final String section) {
         super();
         this.item = item;
         this.section = section;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return item.toString();
    }

}
```

Updated Code:

```
 SectionOutageListItem[] exampleArray = new SectionOutageListItem[outnums.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < outnums.size(); i++) {
        exampleArray[i] = 
      new SectionOutageListItem("Impact", impacted.get(i), "Outage No. " + outnums.get(i)),
      new SectionOutageListItem("status", status.get(i), "Outage No. " + outnums.get(i));


    }
        CustomOutageDetailListAdapter adapter = new CustomOutageDetailListAdapter(this, exampleArray);
        sectionAdapter = new SectionOutageListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(),
                adapter);
```

Comment: In the for block your settings exampleArray = new SectionListItem[]{

                new SectionListItem("test", tests.get(i)), Each time it is recreating a new SectionListItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++) {
        exampleArray = new SectionListItem[]{
                new SectionListItem("test", tests.get(i)),
        };
    }
```

For each element in tests, you are creating a new exampleArray with a single item.

You should use:

```
SectionListItem[] exampleArray = new SectionListItem[tests.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++) {
        exampleArray[i] = new SectionListItem("test", tests.get(i)),
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that at first the comma behind the get(i)) was throwing me off.

Comment: how can I make that an array of arrays please look at updated code.

Comment: Instead of using array of arrays, I suggest you setting all info about the single item inside the object SectionListItem.

Answer (score 0):

Update this code:

```
SectionListItem[] exampleArray = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++) {
        exampleArray = new SectionListItem[]{

                new SectionListItem("test", tests.get(i)),


        };
    }
```

with:

```
SectionListItem[] exampleArray = new SectionListItem[tests.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++) {
        exampleArray[i]= new SectionListItem("test", tests.get(i));
    }
```